# Find caller form name

Tags: delphi

I have created a custom form, to resamble a dialog. Then I overloaded the MessageDlg function in a special unit to call this form. Great, its working A-OK.
When I call the form, it's shown as a Modal, and inside this modal I need the caller form name.

Example: FormA calls unit U_Functions that overloads MessageDlg. Then U_Functions calls FormDLG and it's shown. Inside FormDLG I execute function "GetParentFormName" and it returns "FormA".

I already tried GetForegroundWindow, but it returns the same thing as Self. Self.Parent is null. How can I get the modal caller's reference(TForm)?

Example of flow

FormA:

```
procedure TFormA.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MessageDlg('Call Dialog', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

U_Functions

```
function MessageDlg(Msg: String; Icone: TMsgDlgType; Botoes: TMsgDlgButtons): Integer; overload;
begin
  Result := FormDialog.fn_ShowMessage(msg, Icone, Botoes);
end;
```

FormDialog

```
function FormDialog.fn_ShowMessage(Msg: String; Icone: TMsgDlgType; Botoes: TMsgDlgButtons): Integer;
begin
   // Get FormA's name
end;
```

Comment: Why not just add a `CallerForm` variable to your FormDLG and set its value to the caller when you create it?

Comment: I'd have told before. It's a tree way process. FormA calls MessageDlg that's overloaded by the unit Functions. Then Functions uses FormDLG.

Comment: Then your q needs an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That's for the advice. I was wondering, in this scenario, how would you pass the CallerForm variable, without changing all MessageDlg calls. This function is being implemented on an ERP, with over 9000 forms. Is there a way to accomplish this without changing all MessageDlg calls?

Comment: You might try `Screen.ActiveForm` before showing `FormDialog`, but you really should add an explicit `TForm` parameter to `MessageDlg()` that `FormA` can then pass its `Self` pointer to. Otherwise, you could give `MessageDlg()` a global `var`/`threadvar` variable to hold the `TForm` pointer, so you don't have to change the signature of `MessageDlg()` itself, but you would still have to assign that pointer explicitly before calling `MessageDlg()`.

Comment: If you can arrange that the dialog is a popup window (e.g. bsDialog border style), and don't mess with popup mode (i.e. set it or let it remain pmAuto) then you can get the calling form's handle with GetParent, and then pass the handle to FindControl or iterate forms to get to the calling form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remy Lebeau's approach (Screen.ActiveForm) accomplished exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your time.

Since there's a middle unit, it gathered the callers name, and sent via parameter to the third form (Dialog).